# Why integral and limit can be interchanged

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Consider this integral:
$$
I=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{k^2-k_0^2} k \, \mathrm{d}k
$$
where $x$ and $k_0$ are both *real number* and larger than zero.

This interal does not converge. However, we can "evaluate" it if adding a small imaginary part to $k_0$: $k_0 \to k_0+i\varepsilon$. The result is
$$
i\pi \, e^{i(k_0+i\varepsilon)x}
$$

Finally, we can let $\varepsilon\to 0$:
$$
I=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{k^2-k_0^2} k \, \mathrm{d}k
=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} i\pi \, e^{i(k_0+i\varepsilon)x}
=i\pi \, e^{ik_0 \, x}
$$

Why this procedure can be done?

PS: this integral appears in the derivation of retarded potential in electrodynamics.

Comment: Essentially, because the Fourier transform (which is a good way for understanding how a potential really works) can be defined over the space of [tempered distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform), and some of these Fourier transforms are related to Cauchy principal values, i.e. to a specific way for managing usually non-integrable singularities in a symmetric way. The cornerstone is $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x}\text{ does not exist, but }\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x}=0.$$